# Deploying application in domain failed; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

Tags: deployment, solaris, glassfish-2.x

While deploying any war file in glassfish server 2.1 I am getting the below issue. I have done with small sample web application with hello world in a welcome jsp file in that case as well getting the same issue. Already running war I have undeployed and tried to deploy again. Still the same issue. OS is Solaris.

> Deploying application in domain failed; Error loading deployment descriptors for module [repreg_nov2] Line 1 Column 50 -- Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [repreg_nov2]. White spaces are required between publicId and systemId. Error loading deployment descriptors for module [repreg_nov2] Line 1 Column 50 -- Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [repreg_nov2]. White spaces are required between publicId and systemId

I have deleted the glassfish domain and created again Still the same issue...Please help me ...

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Using the version 2.0 in web.xml solves the problem, it works.